# multiprocessing

Tags: c, multiprocessing

A process pid has two child processes, called pid1 and pid2, now based on a certain condition, some work needs to be assigned to pid1 and some to pid2 at runtime.

```
while(1)
{
 if(x is even)
  {
    send data to pid1 ;
  }
 else
  {
    send data to pid2 ;
  }
 }
```

We need to send some messages to those child processes at run time from the parent process.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: for the start, take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize from socket programming or shared memory for process messaging.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two threads instead of Child processes. Parent shall insert in to two different queues based on data-type (even/odd), say `EvenDataQ` & `OddDataQ`.

1. a thread to process **even x** data; it picks data from `EvenDataQ`
2. another thread to process **odd x** data; it picks data from `OddDataQ`

use a two mutex one for each Queue. Implementation of queue is up to you.

PS:
- threads are lighter than processes.
- easy to implement your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:: You know the PIDs of both child processes.

You can always do this::

```
while(1)
{
 if(x is even && PID_Of_pid1 == PID_Of_First_Child(xxx))
  {
    send data to pid1 ;
  }
 else
  {
    send data to pid2 ;
  }
 }
```

Comment: yes,i know the pids ,but as there is while loop ,so i need to send data ,some text messages ,to these child processes ,in every loop ,i think ,i would try for socket or shared memory,but thanks